# MakePrimitiveSubClassesMutuallyDisjoint doesn't work

Tags: owl, ontology, owl-api

I wanted to use `MakePrimitiveSubClassesMutuallyDisjoint` to make all the subclasses of a class disjoint. But with my code this doesn't happen:

```
OWLClass owlClass = createClass(concept.getId());

// Here I recursively create the subclasses 
processByLevel(skos, owlClass, concept.getNarrowerConcepts());

// But at this point all the subclass should have been created and set as subclasses  
MakePrimitiveSubClassesMutuallyDisjoint primitive = new MakePrimitiveSubClassesMutuallyDisjoint(dataFactory, owlClass, ontology);

manager.saveOntology(ontology);
```

I haven't been able to find an example of how it is used, and I'm not sure if I'm missing a step with the `manager` maybe (something like `addAxiom` but for this).

I can't debug inside the method, but I checked if the subclasses where set after the recursion by calling this:

```
ontology.getSubClassAxiomsForSuperClass(owlClass).size();
```

And the result is the expected one.

But still, I don't see anything on the resulting ontology stating that the classes are disjoint.

Comment: It is a composite change and there is a method `getChanges()` which returns all necessary `OWLOntologyChange` objects. Use the `OWLOntologyManager` on this and `apply` the changes. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OWLClass owlClass = createClass(concept.getId());

// Here I recursively create the subclasses 
processByLevel(skos, owlClass, concept.getNarrowerConcepts());

// But at this point all the subclass should have been created and set as subclasses  
MakePrimitiveSubClassesMutuallyDisjoint primitive = new MakePrimitiveSubClassesMutuallyDisjoint(dataFactory, owlClass, ontology);

// this line is necessary, it actually changes the content of the ontology
manager.applyChanges(primitive.getChanges());

manager.saveOntology(ontology);
```